# One confusing loop or reloop several times

Tags: php, oop

Im building an app using object oriented php and I'm trying to keep the main file that calls each object as readable and linear as possible, but I have an array that needs to be looped through and manipulated across multiple classes.

Im wondering what best practice is in these cases.  Should I have each class loop through the array again and make its changes, or declare all of my objects first and then in one large (more confusing) loop manipulate the array at the same time.  For readability it would be great to just have each object reloop, but is this bad coding?

```
Readability? <--> Best practice?
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see code before making any real assessment, but in general it your problem doesn't sound like you have a conflict between readability and best practices.  Using a single loop, you can achieve both.

Decoupling the array (which is really just another object) from the individual classes is a wise choice, and can be done cleanly without creating too much complication.  Have each class implement an interface for handling an element of this array and then use a single loop to defer action to the individual classes

```
$objectA = new ObjectA();
$objectB = new ObjectB();
$objectC = new ObjectC();

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
  $objectA->doSomething($value, $key, $array);
  $objectB->doSomething($value, $key, $array);
  $objectC->doSomething($value, $key, $array);
}
```

Where do something processes the individual values of the array. As shown above, you can also pass the current key/index and the whole array for context if necessary.